# Background image for wrap_content

Tags: android, image, graphics, layout, background

I created a custom background image and wanted to use it as the background for a layout that has height of **wrap_content**.  However, the total height of the contents of within that layout are much less than the height of the background image.

When I set it as the background in XML via **android:background="@drawable/image"**, I noticed that it displays the entire height of the image, although the height of the actual contents are much shorter.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and was using a 9patch. The full 9 patch image was showing as a background even though the content it was attached to wasn't that big (was using wrap_content). I'm not sure why Android chose to show the full image instead of scaling the background to fit the content.

However, I fixed the problem by scaling down my background image. By that I mean preserving the corners but scaling down the vertical and horizontal portions. See the attached images of the background frame I had before and the result of the resize effort.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I spent some hours on finding out why my 9patch image generated a view that was much higher than it should have been with wrap_content as height parameter. Interestingly enough this effect seems to be device dependant. On a Nexus7 the view height was correct even with the original big background image whereas on an Xperia ray the view height was nearly twice as big as it should have been. On an Xperia mini and on a cheap Android tablet with Cyanogen Mod the "effect" was there as well but not as strong as on the Xperia ray.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your background image to 9-patch drawable or use XML bitmap to alter behavior of your image when it is greater then the container. See [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) for more info about both.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on this if using a XML bitmap? I tried using a XML bitmap and used the property android:gravity="top|fill_horizontal|clip_vertical" to see if that will solve the problem, but it still does not.

Comment: Well, I didn't tried XML bitmap for the case like yours, but the options look promising. The 9-patch way will work for sure -- I've used that already.

Comment: Hmm. I've tried all of the options that might help, but I think I may be doing something wrong. I've searched everywhere online and nobody seems to be having this problem...

Comment: @Konstantin As Steven Pena said in his answer, 9-patch doesn't work for shrinking, only for enlarging.

Comment: @Psycho He also provided a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem. If you set the background's resource is too small, you might have problems with aspect ratio. The solution I found was to divide the background's image in three parts: top, middle and bottom. Each of these images are backgrounds of three different Layouts/ImageViews. The middle part is the one that holds the "wrap_content" property:

Top:
[image: bg_top]

Middle: [image: bg_middle]

Bottom: [image]

As the content's size increase, the borders will keep unaffected and the middle will increase as well (as will the whole "box"). Of course, this is a solution for a case that the partition of your background's image makes sense.